# EKCalendarでcolorやcgColorなどを取得したい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

swiftでiOSのカレンダーアプリを作成しています。

カレンダーの一覧のデータを取得しようとしているのですが、
calendarIdentifier、title、typeは簡単に取得できたのですが、
その他のcolorやcgColor、allowsModifyなどは変数に代入できません。

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
var calendars: [EKCalendar]?
calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(.Event)
let Cal01 = iOSCalendarData()
let calendarIdentifier = calendars![0].calendarIdentifier
let title = calendars![0].title
let type = calendars![0].type
```

このような形で値を取得しようとしているのですが、
colorやcgColor、allowsModifyが取得できません。

ためしにEKCalendarを表示してみると、

```
EKCalendar <0x175271b0> {title = 睡眠; type = CalDAV; allowsModify = YES; color = #FF2968;}
```

このように、ColorやallowsModifyの値を見ることができます。

どのようにすれば、colorやcgColor、allowsModifyの値を取得することができるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アクセスするためのプロパティ名が違っているのではないでしょうか。
AppStoreに、Dashという各種言語のリファレンス・スニペットツールがありまして、
その中のiOSのドキュメントを見ると、Swift2.2においては、

cgColorと呼ばれているものについては、`var CGColor: CGColor`
allowsModifyと呼ばれているものについては、`var allowsContentModifications: Bool { get }`

というプロパティ名が設定されているようなので、

```
let color = calendars![0].CGColor
let allowsModify = calendars![0].allowsContentModifications
```

でアクセス出来ると思います。

Swift3に置いてはコメントでLe Pere d'OOさんが指摘くださったように、

```
let color = calenders![0].cgColor
```

でアクセス出来ると思います。

Comment: Appleの開発者サイトから簡単にたどれるiOSのドキュメントはSwift 3用に更新されてしまっており、ご質問・ご回答にあるようなSwift 2用のドキュメントを見つけるのは難しくなっています。もしURLなどをお持ちでしたらご回答にリンクを記載してもらえませんでしょうか。(`allowsContentModifications`はSwift2でもSwift3でも同じですが。`CGColor`はSwift3では`cgColor`に変更されています。)

Comment: そうでしたか。ご指摘ありがとうございます。僕の場合はDashというリファレンスツールから、EKCalenderクラスのメソッド・プロパティ一覧を検索した結果でした

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。swift初心者で、まさかバージョンによってプロパティ名が変更されているとは思いませんでした。Dashを使って効率的に勉強したいと思います。

Comment: @Чайка さん、ご返信、ツールについての情報の追記等ありがとうございます。そのようなツールがあるのですね、正直全く知りませんでした。また何かの機会がありましたら、その辺りの情報をご共有願えると助かります。